# how to stop empty logs directory to be created on electron app

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

When you start an app built by electron,

C¥Users¥UserName¥AppData¥Roaming¥builtProductName¥logs

the directory would be created.

You can find C¥Users¥UserName¥AppData¥Roaming¥Visual Studio Code¥logs

directory if you are using VSCode.

What is this directory?

And is there any way to prevent this directory to be created, when you build an electron app?

```
// package.json

"build": {
  "productName": "**********"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like `electron-log` is being used. Based on the [log file options](https://github.com/megahertz/electron-log/blob/master/doc/file.md#options), you can provide a `file` option set to a file location you want or disable the file transport altogether with `log.transports.file.level = false;`.